# Why does the way pynput.mouse.Controller is imported matter?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, pypi, pynput

I am using pynput.mouse.Controller to listen for certain mouse actions and also using it to navigate to certain targets.

When I import Controller as follows: `from pynput.mouse import Controller` everything works fine and the programs runs smoothly.

However, when I do this instead `import pynput.mouse.Controller` I receive an error telling **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput.mouse.Controller'**

Unless I am having a fundemental misunderstanding, these lines should function the same. Is there any reason why one produces an error but the other doesn't?

Comment: Could you please add some code that show allows us to reproduce your error?

Comment: `Controller` isn't a module, it's an object that's defined in a module.  Plain `import` only deals with entire modules, you need the `from` form to pick out individual objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import` imports modules or packages (directories with `__init__.py`), it cannot import objects from modules. This doesn't work:

```
import pynput.mouse.Controller
```

This work:

```
import pynput.mouse
Controller = pynput.mouse.Controller
```

This also work:

```
from pynput input mouse
Controller = mouse.Controller
```

And this:

```
from pynput.mouse import Controller
```